# Converting coordinates to EPSG 32620

Tags: coordinate-system

I am new to CRS and wondering how to convert between projections.

From Wikipedia, I have obtained the Lat / Lon values for La Grande Soufirie Volcano which is in Guadeloupe. (16deg 02min 41sec N & 61deg 39min 51 W). I want to convert these coordinates to EPSG 32620. I am aware there are online converters, but the problem is I am not sure what coordinates system my input values are in (16deg 02min 41sec N & 61deg 39min 51 W).

Is it WGS 84 or something else?

Comment: indeed, it is WGS84([EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326)), check Wikipedia's article [La Grande Soufrière](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Grande_Soufri%C3%A8re), where coordinates are `16°02′40.56″N 61°39′51.12″W`.

Comment: This might help https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=La_Grande_Soufri%C3%A8re&params=16_02_40.56_N_61_39_51.12_W_type:mountain_scale:100000 which leads to WGS84 16° 2′ 40.56″ N, 61° 39′ 51.12″ W (16.0446, -61.6642) which shows your coordinates are off by only a part second due to rounding which is approximately 50 feet at the Equator.